# Qt - Why is "&" used?

Tags: c++, qt

At the following web page: http://web.mit.edu/qt-dynamic/www/tutorials-tutorial-t2.html

In:

```
QObject::connect(&quit, SIGNAL(clicked()), &app, SLOT(quit()));
```

Why is **&** used with *quit* and *app*? Cannot we use *quit* and *app* without **&**?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know C or C++? If so, you should know what the operator does and hence what's the difference (plus, you could guess that it doesn't even compile if you omit the `&` because you know how `x` is different from `&x`). If not, perhaps you should first ask what unary `&` does?

Comment: I Suggest you first read a good C++ book, then go to Qt.

Comment: The case is NOT what `&` means. It is why is it used here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QObject::connect` needs *pointers* to two objects. So you have to give it that.

(Since the link you posted is broken, can't be sure of what `quit` and `app` are.)

Comment: +1 and to add to this, & gets the reference pointer of the object.